# WordPress: Display search results by category

Tags: wordpress, search, categories

As the title suggests I'm looking for a simple way of iterating through my categories while populating them with related search results (on a search results template page). Have been looking thorougly for a solution to this but most articles seem to be about altering the form input which I'm not after. Any ideas?

Comment: So you need to sort your search results by category

Comment: Look at [this question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/161553/display-all-posts-in-category-with-specific-tag-posts-at-top), specially the answer by @birgire. It helped me on a similar issue a while ago :-)

Comment: Thanks but it just made me more confused ;)